# Find server for IP resolution in internal network

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

In our company internal network we have two SAP servers (Productive / Test System) which are not member of our Windows Domain.

There hostname is simply `sapprod` and `saptest` - without any FQDN-Suffix like `sapprod.mycompany.com`.

Windows correctly resolves the IP addresses when I ping like `ping sapprod`.
Though, we can not find them being listed anywhere - neither in the "hosts" entry on the local machines, nor in the DNS servers (all three dns-servers respond with *non-existant-domain* when performing a `nslookup`).

Now we need to change the hostnames for a SAP migration.

Where can I find those server names?

Comment: It seems they currently resolve not via DNS, but via NetBios or WINS. This especially looks true because that servers are not joined to domain.

Comment: I strongly recommend you configure those servers to use a domain suffix and give them entries in your local dns server.

Answer (score 1):

It might be using netbios, use `nbtstat -a hostname` to see if it resolves the IP address.
Do a trace route to find out what switch it is connected to.
Or else connect into your switch and look up the mac address table to see if you can find the port No. it is connected to.

Comment: `nbtstat -a sapprod` shows a list of entries containing the server in question amongst other entries. It shows state = registered - does that mean this host is using netbios?

Comment: So it just means that the name exists on the network and it using WIN server to check, you could just run an ip scanner on various subnets to find the ip address and hosname. Try and ssh into the name as well as it is probably a linux server if it is not registered on DNS.